# HL7-dotnetcore: Why the HL7 message validation fail with error "Message Type & Trigger Event value not found in message"?

Tags: c#, .net-core, hl7, hl7-dotnetcore

I am using [HL7-dotnetcore package](https://github.com/Efferent-Health/HL7-dotnetcore) which seems to be really nice. Unfortunately I'm struggling while creating new HL7 message.

I am trying to create new `MDM_T02` message as explained in the [guide (docs)](https://github.com/Efferent-Health/HL7-dotnetcore#adding-a-message-header) with following code:

```
Message mdmMessage = new Message();

mdmMessage.AddSegmentMSH(
    "sendingApplication",
    "sendingFacility",
    "receivingApplication",
    "receivingFacility",
    string.Empty,
    "MDM_T02",
    $"Id{DateTime.Now.Ticks}",
    "P",
    "2.6");
```

But, I get following exception message:

> Failed to validate the message with error - Message Type & Trigger Event value not found in message

The [`AddSegmentMSH`](https://github.com/Efferent-Health/HL7-dotnetcore/blob/master/src/Message.cs#L601) method expects the `messageType` as a parameter. But I don't know about the trigger event. I think the exception comes from [here](https://github.com/Efferent-Health/HL7-dotnetcore/blob/master/src/Message.cs#L789). Does someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are sending `messageType` as `MDM_T02`. This is invalid value. The `MDM` is message and `T02` is an event. Those should be separated by component separator; default CAPS (`^`) symbol. Observe that you are separating those with underscore (`_`) symbol.

Due to this, toolkit is not able to validate your message type. You should change `"MDM_T02"` to `"MDM^T02"`.

Refer to following code on [github](https://github.com/Efferent-Health/HL7-dotnetcore/blob/master/src/Message.cs#L773):

```
var MSH_9_comps = MessageHelper.SplitString(MSH_9, this.Encoding.ComponentDelimiter);

if (MSH_9_comps.Count >= 3)
{
    this.MessageStructure = MSH_9_comps[2];
}
else if (MSH_9_comps.Count > 0 && MSH_9_comps[0] != null && MSH_9_comps[0].Equals("ACK"))
{
    this.MessageStructure = "ACK";
}
else if (MSH_9_comps.Count == 2)
{
    this.MessageStructure = MSH_9_comps[0] + "_" + MSH_9_comps[1];
}
else
{
    throw new HL7Exception("Message Type & Trigger Event value not found in message", HL7Exception.UNSUPPORTED_MESSAGE_TYPE);
}
```

Observe that the exception being thrown in above code is same that you mentioned in question. Also observe the first line; the `SplitString` is done on `ComponentDelimiter`.